# How do I manipulate a 3D point plot?

Tags: animation

I currently have a recursion done in 3D.

At the moment, I am able to manipulate the points, but I cannot use "Joined->True" to connect them
Currently this is what I have

```
z[1, t_] := {1, 1, 1};
A3[t_] := {{1, -t, 0}, {t, 1, -t}, {0, t, t + 1}}
W[t_] := Inverse[(IdentityMatrix[3] + A3[t])];
z[n_Integer, t_] /; n > 0 := W[t].z[n - 1, t];

Manipulate[
 ListPointPlot3D[Table[z[n, t], {n, 1, 10}], Mesh -> Full, 
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 1], {t, 0, 
  1}]
```

Any idea on how to connect the points?

Comment: Yes. Don't know why I did that

Comment: I deleted my comment, since it's fixed now.  I'll delete this one later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Line@#, PointSize@Large, Red, Point@#} &@ Table[z[n, t], {n, 1, 10}], 
            PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]